# View-Model Coroutines multi execute

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I call a View-Model method from a fragment. After screen rotation, my View-Model is called again. I need to don't destroy my created View-Model because of its values.
I know it is possible to handle it with Coroutines job.
Can you tell me if We have a better method for doing it?

ViewModel

```
    private var _counterViewModelLiveData = MutableLiveData(0)
val counterViewModelLiveData
    get() = _counterViewModelLiveData
private var job: Job? = null

fun startVmCounter() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1))
            _counterViewModelLiveData.value = _counterViewModelLiveData.value!! + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
    private fun viewModelSaveState(){
    vm.startVmCounter()
    vm.counterViewModelLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        binding.txtViewmodelSaveStateCounter.text = it.toString()
    }
}
```

Also, I know about SavedStateHandle, but I don't want to destroy my created ViewModel and fetch data again with SavedStateHandle.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are retrieving the ViewModel correctly, it shouldn't be recreated. From the code you posted the issue could be that you call `viewModelSaveState` again after your *Fragment* is recreated. You want to call `startVmCounter` only the first time the Fragment is created. To know if that's the case, you can check if the `Bundle` you get (for example) in `onViewCreated` is null. On the other hand, it's correct that you call `vm.counterViewModelLiveData.observe` every time, because otherwise you won't get updates after recreation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean something that looks like the below code.  
 `if (savedInstanceState == null)`  
 `vm.startVmCounter()`  
 `viewModelSaveState()`

Comment: Yes. So `vm.startVmCounter()` is called only when `savedInstanceState == null`, while `viewModelSaveState()` is called every time (and now should only contain the call to `observe`).

Comment: Yes, I know. Thank you for your answer. However, in my opinion, it is better to have more boilerplate code in the ViewModel than having a condition in Fragment.
isn't it?

Comment: If you fancy that, another option is to move the call to `startVmCounter()` to the ViewModel's `init` block, but executing this kind of code in constructors might be considered a bad practice depending on who you ask.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, it could be a good solution for some specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Just place your code from `viewModelSaveState()` into `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.

So the observation is only started when creating the Fragment and not when the configuration changed.

Comment: If you mean, to move the method from ViewModel to Fragment, it's not a good idea.
Because it is a kind of logic and as I know it should be implemented in the ViewModel class.

Comment: No, I did't mean this. Just move your code from your fragment method `viewModelSaveState` to the `onCreateView` method of you fragment.